# django allauth redirecting to home url

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-1.8

I'm using django 1.8 with python 3.4
I've integrated django allauth using the link :
http://www.sarahhagstrom.com/2013/09/the-missing-django-allauth-tutorial/

Now, when I try to open http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login .. It redirects me to http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Any idea, why is this happening?

Answer (score 5):

It's probably because you are logged in. 
Go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/logout` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

url.py

```
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'accounts/login.html'}, name='login'),
url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout_then_login', name='logout'),
```

settings.py

```
#LOGIN AND
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGOUT_URL = '/logout/'
```

Comment: made the changes, still getting same redirection.. btw i've haven't given any path for auth templates

Comment: It worked now. but http://localhost:8000/login is working but not http://localhost:8000/acounts/login . what changes should I make to make http://localhost:8000/acounts/login work?

Comment: @AjaySingh Change the url from `url(r'^login/$'` to `url(r'^accounts/login/$',`

Comment: @AjaySingh in main url:     # Accounts
    url(r'^', include('apps.accounts.urls')),